# Rendering fake data in UI in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, ninject

I am working on an MVC 4 application where I have come to a point where I need to render fake repositories to show dummy data on the UI.

I am using Ninject and Entity framework.

One of my thoughts was to create a new configuration i.e.currently there is release or debug. I was going to create a Dev configuration which will then need to be checked when binding via inject. So i could add a block to use fake repositories when in dev mode.

has anyone tried it a different way?

Cheers

Comment: Proceed this way. IoC is all about such substitution

Comment: Do you use XML for configuring Ninject?

Comment: I do not use xml for comfiguring ninject. Currently using the bootstrap module where it registers the services when app starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Castle.Windsor for IoC but the idea is absolutly the same:

**Repositories installer:**

```
/*    container.Register(Classes
                           .FromAssemblyNamed("XProject.DataAccess")
                           .Where(t =>
                                  t.Name.EndsWith("Repository") &&
                                  t.Name.StartsWith("Base") == false &&
                                  t.IsClass).LifestyleSingleton());*/
```

**Fake repositories installer:**

```
container.Register(Classes
                       .FromAssemblyNamed("XProject.DataAccess")
                       .Where(t =>
                              t.Name.EndsWith("FakeRepository") &&
                              t.Name.StartsWith("Base") == false &&
                              t.IsClass).LifestyleSingleton());
```

I would put registrations together and comment/uncomment one of it.

The better way is to define config setting inside Web.config.

Optionally you can use conditional compilation:

```
#if DEBUG

//Registration code

#endif
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691099(v=vs.71).aspx